# Three.js: How to update wireframeHelpers position?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I added a `WireframeHelper` to my scene like this:

```
var wfh = new THREE.WireframeHelper(mesh, 0x000000);
wfh.material.linewidth = 2;
scene.add(wfh);
```

How do I change the wireframeHelpers position?

I tried:
`wfh.position.x += 10;`

and

```
 wfh.matrixAutoUpdate = true
 wfh.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(10, 0, 0));
```

The second one moves my `wireframeHelper` but not to the position it should move.

Comment: It is designed to be located where the mesh is. Move the mesh.

Comment: I switched from moving my geometry to moving my mesh and it works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WireframeHelper` will move, automatically, when the mesh is moved. Move the mesh, instead.

If you want to see only the helper, you can set `mesh.visible = false`, but the mesh must be included in the scene graph.

three.js r.65